# Using Join and Union to combine results from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already have a result set using join from multiple master tables with TABLE A as the primary table. Now I'm trying to perform union on table B with joins from masters retained.

This is the query I tried:

```
select 
    t1.* 
from 
    (select 
         id, mobile, email, pan 
     from a  
     union
     select  
         b_id, mobile, email, pan
     from b) as t1,
    ci.status,
    ab.desc
from 
    a 
left join 
    cuI ci on ci.id = a.id
left join 
    abMaster ab on ab.id = a.id
where 
    a.id is not null 
order by 
    a.created_on desc
```

This didn't work

Comment: *This didn't work* isn't a very precise description of your problem. **WHAT** happens? Nothing? The wrong data gets selected? No data gets selected? Do you get an error - if so: ***what*** is that error?

Comment: I get syntax error

Comment: In Your query  you  have several error and  is not clear your goal .. then update your question add a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Please learn the very significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL. In general, you should default to using UNION ALL to avoid the cost of duplicate removal (especially if it is not needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first look your have several error

some column name  `ci.status,  ab.descin` wrong place,

two from clase

a reference at table a that should be (probably) a reference to t1

a possible valid query could be

```
select  t1.* , ci.status, ab.desc
from 
    (select id, mobile, email, pan 
     from a  
     union
     select b_id, mobile, email, pan
     from b
) as t1 
left join 
    cuI ci on ci.id = t1.id
left join 
    abMaster ab on ab.id = t1.id
where 
    t1.id is not null 
order by 
    t1.created_on desc
```